# Power BI problem in direct active relationship

Tags: powerbi, relationship, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem with Power BI in the use of multiple direct active relationship between two table.

I have this 2 table: Population and Cost and I want to graph the the costs over the years in the different regions according to the population of the region.

In Population the attributes of my interest are: **Year**, **Region**, **#Population**, insted in Cost I have: **Year**, **Region**, **Costs**. So I need to create two active relationship between Year and Region in the two tables. However I can't do that in Power BI.

I tryed to generate a new Population table (an identical copy of the other) and create the two active relationship: the first (for Years) between Cost and one Population, the second (for Region) between Cost and the other Population.

Unfortunately this solution is not successful, in fact, by dividing the costs for the population, in one case I obtain the aggregation over all the years, in the other the aggregation of all regions.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Each Power BI relationship is limited to a single column from each table.  The typical workaround to your scenario is to create a concatenated column on each table.

You can do this in the Query Editor (my preference) using the Merge Columns button from the Add Column ribbon.

The other method would be using the Add Column button (e.g. on the Modeling ribbon) and writing the DAX formula e.g.

Year Region Key = [Year] & [Region]

Once you have a concatenated column added to both tables, use that to create the active relationship.